# Итерация двух списков.(Сравнение трех из одного и двух из другого)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сравнение

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Как провести параллельную итерацию в Python что бы сравнивалось три элемента из 'a' и два из 'b'.

Например

Если 3>2 and 2>1 and 12>11, то....

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
b = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

for i, j in zip(range(2, len(a)), range(1, len(b))):
  if a[i] > a[i-1] and a[i-1] > a[i-2] and b[j] > b[j-1]:
    print('ok')
```

Только по условию непонятно, что делать с последним элементом `b`. Тут `20` не обрабатывается, например.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то ребуется просто в одном `if`указать несколько списков, например:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
b = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
if a[1]>a[2] and a[2]>a[3] and b[1]>b[2]:
 print("Ура!")
```